# iPhone Webapp Splash Screen White-Space

Tags: iphone, jquery-mobile, mobile-safari, splash-screen, homescreen

I have a mobile webapp that I am developing using jquery mobile. I am prompting the users that they can use the [add to homescreen](http://cubiq.org/add-to-home-screen) function to load the webapp from the desktop. When I test the functionality of the splash screen on my iPhone 3GS, the png file which I wish to load does not load with the splash screen, but rather, a "screen shot" of the site with a white-space at the top where it appears the address bar used to be.

Here is my code

```
<html><head>

<title>Page Title</title>
<meta content='yes' name='apple-mobile-web-app-capable'> 
<meta content='default' name='apple-mobile-web-app-status-bar-style'> 
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=0;" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/jquery.mobile.1.min.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/mydashboard.min.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/add2home.css">

<link rel="apple-touch-icon-precomposed" href="touch-icon-iphone.png" />
<link rel="apple-touch-icon-precomposed" sizes="72x72" href="touch-icon-ipad.png" />
<link rel="apple-touch-icon-precomposed" sizes="114x114" href="touch-icon-iphone4.png" />

<!-- ***Here is my code for splash screen*** -->
<link rel="apple-touch-startup-image" href="Default.png" />
<link rel="apple-touch-startup-image" href="touch-splash-ipad-land.png"  media="screen and (min-device-width: 481px) and (max-device-width: 1024px) and (orientation:landscape)" />
<link rel="apple-touch-startup-image" href="touch-splash-ipad-port.png" media="screen and (min-device-width: 481px) and (max-device-width: 1024px) and (orientation:portrait)" />

<!-- ***My JS files are included under this and the closing of the head tag*** -->
```

I have tried a 320x460 and a 320x480 png file where the Default.png is. Neither have had any success. From what I've read, I think I'm doing this right, but I could be wrong. I'm basing my opinion on https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/qa/qa1588/_index.html 
and 
https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariWebContent/ConfiguringWebApplications/ConfiguringWebApplications.html

So my question is this, has anyone else seen this? If so, what was the cause and what did you do to resolve the issue if you did resolve the issue? If you haven't seen this particular issue, is there anything you might be able to suggest based on my code above?

Comment: is Default.png 320 x 460? What are the permissions on the file? is it in a different directory then the webapp? Maybe move the link right after the last meta tag

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. The **Default.png** file MUST be 320x460px.
2. Try removing the launcher from the home screen and re-adding it from Safari.

That is what I had to do to get mine to work.